# Combining C with Python

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

I'd like to mix C code with Python GUI libraries. I thought about creating C library and using it with ctypes. How to create library for both Linux and Windows at the same time? On Linux, I simply use `gcc -fPIC -shared -o lib.so main.c`, but how to do that for Windows?

Comment: There is more than one way to solve the problem. The standard docs are a good start: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/windows.html#building-c-and-c-extensions-on-windows

Comment: I have some troubles with creating .dll, but .so works well on Linux. One of my C functions returns 2D array of integers. How can i assign that array to Python variable?

Answer (score -1):

Many IDE for C/C++ already prepared DLL program template,such as Visual Studio,Code::Blocks,VC++6.0 etc.. Using DLL files is similar to using SO files